# In buffer overflow, how new return address aligns perfectly?

Tags: memory, x86, stack, buffer-overflow, security

I'm confused that in stack based buffer overflow, if I overwrite a program's return address with a new target address in that stack eliment, how those addresses align or how to make sure that happens? For example: let say in a stack frame I have a variable element at address 0x1 (just pretend although 0x1 is too low for that to happen) and I have a return address element at address 0x6. Now if the architecture is 32 bit in my processor then the address will be of 4 bytes. So If the program asks me for a argument which it will put into that buffer and I supply that address two times repeated then clearly that address element will have the second byte of the new address. Thus the address is not aligned and the program will crash. How will I make sure that the address will always align?

```
let new address = 0x bf ff ff 3c

address from buffer to return address element:  | 0x1 | 0x2 | 0x3 | 0x4 | 0x5 | 0x6 | ....
                                               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     
newly written return address layout in memory: | 3c  | ff   | ff   | bf  | 3c  | ff   | ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You choose the contents that you're overflowing with.  Make it the right length to line up the return address with its location relative to the buffer in the stack frame of the binary you're exploiting.

That distance is a compile-time constant (or at least `n%16` is constant if it's a VLA or alloca...) so you can find it with a disassembler.  Compilers will choose to align even local arrays by 16<sup>1</sup>.  Or at least by 4 on 32-bit ABIs that don't require 16-byte stack alignment.  So even if you don't have a copy of the binary you're trying to exploit, you may still be able to repeat the return address as you suggest, at positions aligned by 4 relative to the start of the
buffer.  Of course, knowing what return address to use (for a ROP attack) may be hard without a binary, unless there are some libraries that aren't ASLRed.

(e.g. the x86-64 System V ABI requires this for all arrays >=16 bytes, and all VLAs, despite private local arrays not being visible outside of a single function.)